# How to display the content of a txt file from Google drive in html

Tags: html

I've been working on something that could appear to be stupid I know... anyway.. here is what I am trying to do.

Let me give you some background information.

I created a website with Google Site and everything is ok

I need to show the content of a txt file which is in my google drive.

To help you understand what I intent to do. It's a kind of message that I want to show in my website, on one of the pages that I have created with google site.

The idea is that I don't want to go to google site and edit the text. Instead I want to edit the txt file with the idea of showing it.

I hope I have explained myself well enough ( I am Spanish. I am an English learner )

Thanks for your help

Edited to show an example that doesn't work but shows what I intent

Not supported

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if your website located in your PC. Then you can edit all relevant files as you say in text files, but .html rather .txt).